# How to convert Excel Table to JSON efficiently?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, excel

I have table in Excel and i want to convert it in JSON, one way is to save each cross-section cell as a seaprate entity, but I want the efficietive way to introduce the table in JSON

```
For example,
    146 281 175
202 10  6   6
117 8   8   8
210 7   6   6
290 5   9   5
182 8   8   6
```

Each column respresents the width and each row represents the height, and there is some corresponding value where these two meet in a cell, e.g., 281 and 210 responds to 6.
How to convert this table efficiently, and get the results in a webpage where user enter the width and height?

Converted this very table in 2D array but this is not correct way I am looking for

```
[["P1","146","281","175"],["202","10","6","6"],["117","8","8","8"],["210","7","6","6"],["290","5","9","5"],["182","8","8","6"]]
```

Comment: [Here](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/exceljs) is a JavaScript library that will convert the excel document to a JSON file for you.

Comment: For the structure you show, [Tim Hall's VBA tool](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON) can also produce the result you show from the 2D array of the range.